# Why is the View Close Votes privelige not available to new users?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, privileges

I expected that this question would have been asked already, but after a good search effort I could not find it. Hopefully I will not receive close votes!

I am curious why this feature was made a 250 rep privilege, when it seems like it would be the most useful tool for new users to learn what they are doing wrong when asking questions.
I appreciate that new users should read the provided guide material before posting, but we all know that nobody likes 'reading the manual'. The number of questions that I see on a daily basis that should, and probably do, receive close votes is very frustrating and they are almost always asked by users with less than 250 reputation.
I also appreciate that more experienced users should inform of reasons for adding a close vote using the comments feature, but many do not.

By the time a user reaches 250 reputation, I would hope that this feature would be redundant as the user would have a good understanding of what qualifies as a closable question and would no longer be receiving close votes.

So, why make it a privilege to be earned? I think it would be most beneficial to users with no/low reputation.